# How to do triple Difference-in-difference with "FIXEST" R package

Tags: r

I need to do a triple DiD and I am using sunab function in FIXEST package in R. Is it possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.